# Using getDocumentByKey: 'Undefined' is not a function

Tags: dominotogo

I'm trying to enter a notes document by using the getDocumentByUNID function. Running the following code snipped outputs an error:

```
    var unid = (function() {
        for (var x in e.row.children) {
            if (e.row.children[x].content == "id") {
                return e.row.children[x].text;
            }
        }
    })();

    if (!unid) {
        YN.exception("Function displayGeraet: Document ID could not be found!");
    } else {
        var Geraete_db  = app.notes_db_geraete;

        YN.log("Unid: "+unid);          //Output: Unid: 22EC92ED5AF33138C1257BA30053E753
        YN.log("URL: "+Geraete_db.baseURL);     //Output: URL: http://MT04.wd.isernhagen/HKMT/Ticket/Geraete.nsf

        var Geraete_doc = Geraete_db.getDocumentbyUNID(unid); //EXCEPTION: openGeraet, TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'db.getDocumentbyUNID(unid)')
```

Any suggestions what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

do you have "Geraete_db.getDocumentByUNID(unid)" with "By" in uppercase or with lower case as in your code sample?
It should be getDocumentByUNID().

Comment: Thank you, Julian. That did the trick! For your information: I copied the code from the wiki:

http://youatnotes.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-dtg.nsf/dx/NotesDocument

The code-examples are written in lower case there.

Comment: thanks for the hint about the wiki, the typo is fixed now. Please don't forget to vote for my answer :)